# Java – Issue referencing an object's name during run-time

Tags: java

I'm trying to reference an object's name during run-time in a small Java console program, but I am unable to. My console keeps returning "VirtualFriend@17dfafd1" instead of the actual name of the VirtualFriend object that I pass in the parameter. How do I convert this to an actual String that shows the name of the object instead of its hash code? Here's the code for reference:

```
public class VirtualFriend {

    // variables
    private String myName;
    private int myAge, myFood;

    // other variables
    private int a, b;
    private VirtualFriend other;

    // general constructor
    public VirtualFriend() {
        myName = "Unknown";
        myAge = 5;
        myFood = 2;
    }

    // specific constructor
    public VirtualFriend(String myName, int myAge) {
        this.myName = myName;
        this.myAge = myAge;
        myFood = 2;
    }

    // name methods
    public void setName(String myName) {
        this.myName = myName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return myName;
    }

    // integer method
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        return a + b;
    }

    // void methods
    public void printName() {
        System.out.println(myName);
    }

    public void greet(VirtualFriend other) {
        this.other = other;
        System.out.println("Hi there " + other + ". It's nice "
                + "to meet you. My name is " + myName + ".");
    }

    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        VirtualFriend Liz = new VirtualFriend("Liz", 16);
        VirtualFriend Boo = new VirtualFriend("Boo", 16);

        Liz.greet(Boo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either call `getName()` or implement `toString()`.

Comment: @Andreas How would I implement toString()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `other.getName()` in your print statement. A variable called `name` has no special meaning in Java; when it sees an object concatenated with a string, it tries to call the `toString()` method on that object. If that object does not define `toString()`, then (via inheritance from the `object` object) it calls the ["default" `toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method, which returns the string you observed; classname@hashcode.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we want any class  to represent itself in string form, the `toString()` function is called. It is defined in `Object` class. So it will be in every class. This `toString()` function return the name of the class with its hash code.

If you want to change it's behaviour, just override this function.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return myName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `+` operator to concatenate strings, Java will let you use any object as one of the operands, if the other is a string.  In that case, there is an implied `toString()` call on the object.  So your `println` is actually this:

```
    System.out.println("Hi there " + other.toString() + ". It's nice "
            + "to meet you. My name is " + myName.toString() + ".");
```

All objects have `toString()`, but by default, the result will look something like `Class@xxxxxxxx` where the x's are hex digits.  If you want a reasonable-looking `toString()`, you have to override it yourself in your class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return <whatever String expression you want>;
}
```

Many of the classes defined by Java already have `toString()` overrides.  The `String` type itself has `toString()` overridden, and it just returns the string (so that `myName.toString()` is the same as `myName`).  But your own class won't have a built-in override.  (Also, arrays don't have `toString()` overridden, and you need to use `Arrays.toString(arr)` to make a string out of an array.)

Answer (score 1):

-Whenever we print any java object then by default It prints something like class@xxxx...

-But if you want to print object with it's associated value then you need to override toString() method in that class.